# How to play a wav file on high frequency?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, playback, frequency, resampling

Do you have any idea on converting my wav audio data to high frequency playback. 
I am creating a module that plays a melody wav file in 16-20khz frequency.

any idea?

-tong

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific ? Do you just want to shift a 0-4 kHz baseband signal up to 16-20 kHz ?

Comment: I have a tone(a wav file) sampling rate is 44.1khz 16bit mono. this  will playback at 13khz(audible)... too noisy...I want to convert it to 16khz or 20khz that is not audible. purpose of it is for experiment, sending non audible soundwave to other machine then that second machine will convert that 19khz(sample) tone to a 13khz tone again...

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways of doing this and it will depend whether you have any temporal information that you want to preserve, or whether you can just effectively increase the sample rate so that the frequency is scaled up (and the duration scaled down).

You didn't mention anything about OS, programming language, sound API, etc, so it's impossible to give specific solutions, but if your sound API allows you to change the playback rate than you may just be able to scale this up by a suitable factor. If not then you will need to resample the sound to achieve the same effect. There are plenty of third party libraries out there for resampling (upsampling/downsampling).

If you need to preserve temporal information then things get a little trickier and you'll need to look at pitch shifting algorithms, e.g. phase vocoder.

Comment: thanks for that information, it help a lot...
I am operating on windows application, temporal information need not to preserve...as long as the receive can have the related output...